# Javascript Alert box is not showing

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, prototype

I am currently learning Object oriented Javascript but it seems that the alert is not working. what is the problem here?

```
<

html>
 <head>
  <script>

   function professor(name, myLecture){
        this.name = name;
        this.myLecture = myLecture;
   }

   professor.prototype.display = function(){
        return this.name + " is teaching " + this.myLecture;
   };

   function subjectList(subject){
        this.subject = subject;
   }

   subjectList.prototype.showAll= function(){
            var str = " " ;
            for(var i = 0 ; i<subject.length; i++ )
            str+= this.subject[i].display();
            return str;
   };

   var ListOfSubs = new subjectList([
        new professor("Muy","Obprog")
   ]);

   alert(ListOfSubs.showAll());

  </script>
   <body>
   </body>
 </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you opened up the JavaScript debugger in the browser you are using and seeing if there are any errors there?

Comment: Make sure your javascript has no errors first (ReferenceError: subject is not defined - line 17)

Comment: Use a debugger ... error i get is 'subject is not defined'

Comment: for(var i = 0 ; i<subject.length; i++ ) to for(var i = 0 ; i<this.subject.length; i++ )

Comment: Try to wrap your `alert` in a self-executing anonymous function like so: `(function(){ alert(ListOfSubs.showAll()); })();`

Comment: @ign how do you do that? I am using chrome

Comment: @RémiBreton just curious, what's the purpose/advantage of doing that?

Comment: @user962206 F12 -> Console (on Windows). Paste the code and Execute (Enter). Also, Tools -> Console will do the trick.

Comment: @user962206 You can be browsing any site... The console just executes your code. There should be more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965/how-do-i-use-the-javascript-console-in-google-chrome

Comment: @ign I assume since the console returns no errors, the `alert` function is just not being executed in the `<head>` as it should. I may be wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `this.subject.length` instead of `subject.length`.

Comment: why use this.subject.length? rather the later?

Comment: `'subject'` is not 'visible' within `'showAll'` method. So you need to use `'this'`

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
 for(var i = 0 ; i<subject.length; i++ )
```

The error was that "Subject is not defined".
Changing it from subject.length = **this**.subject.length should fix your problem.

It should output:

```
Muy is teaching Obprog
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `this.`

```
   subjectList.prototype.showAll= function(){
            var str = " " ;
            for(var i = 0 ; i< this.subject.length; i++ ) // notice this.subject
            str+= this.subject[i].display();
            return str;
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Other have informed you about the reason what is wrong with your js-code.

One more note from me.

Usually an programmed alert will not come up when an exception happens before.

And by the way, your body-tag should be after the closing head-tag

Answer (score 0):

This code will work inside your script tag:

```
 function professor(name, myLecture){
        this.name = name;
        this.myLecture = myLecture;
   }

   professor.prototype.display = function(){
        return this.name + " is teaching " + this.myLecture;
   };

   function subjectList(subject){
        this.subject = subject;
   }

   subjectList.prototype.showAll= function(){
            var str = " " ;
            for(var i = 0 ; i<subject.length; i++ )
            str+= this.subject[i].display();
            return str;
   };

   var ListOfSubs = new subjectList([
        new professor("Muy","Obprog")
   ]);

   alert(ListOfSubs.showAll());
```

Cause: in your showAll function you have used subject, which is not existent, but the object of your prototype has a member called subject. So instead of `i<subject.length`, `i<this.subject.length` is fixing your problem.